# Calling @PatchMapping annotated method using TestRestController

Tags: spring, request-mapping

I have a method annotated with `@PatchMapping`.

```
@PatchMapping(path= "/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return")
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> returnBookTransaction(@PathVariable(name="transaction-id") Long transactionId){
    Transaction transaction = transactionRepository.findById(transactionId).get();
    transaction.setDateOfReturn(LocalDateTime.now());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(transaction);
}
```

I need to test this method. In test method, I need to use `TestRestController.patchForObject();`

```
@Test
public void testReturnBookTransaction() throws Exception {

    ResponseEntity<Transaction> response = testRestTemplate.patchForObject("/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return", 
            , Transaction.class, 1);

    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

}
```

The code above shows compiler error in `template.patchForObject()`, as it needs 4 parameters. I don't know, what to pass in 4th parameter.

I just have to pass 1 for {transaction-id}, URL String and return type class, which I have already passed. But this method requires one more parameter as `Object`.

I don't know, what to pass in `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html#patchForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-):

> public  T patchForObject(**String url,
>                               Object request,
>                               Class responseType,
>                               Map uriVariables**)
>                        throws RestClientException

The second argument is for request object. Since you don't have any request-related info in your controller method, you can set it to null.

Try the following:

```
Transaction response = testRestTemplate.patchForObject("/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return", null 
        , Transaction.class, 1);
```

UPDATE:

If you want to have access to the response entity, try the following:

```
ResponseEntity<Transaction> response = testRestTemplate.exchange("/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return", HttpMethod.PATCH, null,Transaction.class, 1);
```

Comment: patchForObject() is returning only Transaction object. But my returnBookTransaction() method returns ResponseEntity<Transaction>.

Comment: It doesn't cause any call. Nothing happens on using exchange() method. NO error logs printed. Nothing happens.